# Play music file with Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mp3

I want the user to be give me an URL that ends with the .mp3 extension and be played in the `show` page.

I used scaffolding to create the new page for the User to submit the URL, and in the show page I want this URL to be play the associated media file:

```
<p>
<strong>Music url:</strong>
<%= @profile_music.music_url %>
</p>
```

If it was an ordinary HMTL page I would use:

```
<EMBED SRC= "url.mp3" width="360" height="165" HIDDEN=false AUTOSTART=true loop="false" volume="60">
```

So I need something like:

```
<EMBED SRC= @profile_music.music_url width="360" height="165" HIDDEN=false AUTOSTART=true loop="false" volume="60">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
<EMBED SRC="<%= @profile_music.music_url %>"
    width="360" height="165" HIDDEN=false AUTOSTART=true loop="false" volume="60">
```

`<%= @profile_music.music_url %>` will be interpreted by erb with the actual content.